# Создания массива с неопределенным кол-ом элементов

Tags: java, массивы

Есть варианты создания одномерного массива который нужно заполнить элементами с ввода клавиатуры неизвестное кол-во раз?

Или только вводить в список arrList а потом закинуть в массив?

```
int[] mas = new int[arrayList.size()];
```

Comment: Можно каждый раз переопределять массив, но зачем? Используйте более гибкие коллекции, не понимаю этого помешательства именно на массивах.

Comment: Можете еще как вариант сделать массив максимальной длины и потом обрезать его если стоит задача использовать только массивы. Но это еще более кривой хак, чем перезапись массива.

Answer (score 1):

> Есть варианты создания одномерного массива который нужно заполнить элементами с ввода клавиатуры неизвестное кол-во раз?

**Нет**. Массив всегда имеет предопределенный размер. Как вариант (но не стоит так делать) - создать массив максимальной длины (эта величина зависит от JVM, в старых значение равно `Integer.MAX_VALUE-5` ([Do Java arrays have a maximum size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size)
), на моей версии jvm сейчас это `Integer.MAX_VALUE-2`), а по окончании заполнения - урезать до нужной длины.

> Или только вводить в список arrList а потом закинуть в массив?

Лучше не использовать `ArrayList`, т.к. под капотом у него тот же массив и при добавлении элементов время от времени он будет пересоздаваться, а содержимое копироваться. Лучше использовать связанный список - `LinkedList`. Добавление в его конец имеет константное время и не требует копирования содержимого. Затем создадите массив из всех элементов списка:

```
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
//добавление элементов
Integer[] array = list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);
```

Comment: Вы не поверите, но `LinkedList` даже в таком кейсе проигрывает `ArrayList` https://gist.github.com/izebit/25422ef57284b5b6849dfe6358b61aa2

Comment: может сразу создавать очередь? все равно из середины читать не нужно